# Show/hide elements won't display all elements initially

Tags: javascript, html

I'm implementing a show/hide elements filter. It works, but all elements are supposed to display initially and are instead hidden. The 'active' class is not being removed/added to buttons either.

Getting this console error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByClassName' of null at custom.js:40
```

Here's the live site: https://michaelfreundlaw.com/all-cases.html

HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Categories</h1>
        <div id="myBtnContainer" class="btn-group-vertical">
          <button class="btn active" onclick="filterSelection('all')"> Show all</button>
          <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('00s')"> 2000s</button>
          <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('90s')"> 1990s</button>
          <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('80s')"> 1980s</button>
          <button class="btn" onclick="filterSelection('70s')"> 1970s</button>
        </div>
        <h1>Cases</h1>
        <div class="container">
            <article class="filterDiv 00s">
                <h2>'00s Case Name</h2>
            </article>
            <article class="filterDiv 90s">
                <h2>'90s Case Name</h2>
            </article>
            <article class="filterDiv 80s">
                <h2>'80s Case Name</h2>
            </article>
            <article class="filterDiv 70s">
                <h2>'70s Case Name</h2>
            </article>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.filterDiv {
  float: left;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2px;
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
}

/* The "show" class is added to the filtered elements */
.show {
  display: block;
}

/* Style the buttons */
.btn {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Add a light grey background on mouse-over */
.btn:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Add a dark background to the active button */
.btn.active {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}
```

Javascript:

```
filterSelection("all")
function filterSelection(c) {
  var x, i;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("filterDiv");
  if (c == "all") c = "";
  // Add the "show" class (display:block) to the filtered elements, and remove the "show" class from the elements that are not selected
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    w3RemoveClass(x[i], "show");
    if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) w3AddClass(x[i], "show");
  }
}

// Show filtered elements
function w3AddClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {
      element.className += " " + arr2[i];
    }
  }
}

// Hide elements that are not selected
function w3RemoveClass(element, name) {
  var i, arr1, arr2;
  arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
  arr2 = name.split(" ");
  for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
      arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);
    }
  }
  element.className = arr1.join(" ");
}

// Add active class to the current control button (highlight it)
var btnContainer = document.getElementById("myBtnContainer");
var btns = btnContainer.getElementsByClassName("btn");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
  btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
    this.className += " active";
  });
}
```

Comment: Probably your JS is being executed before the DOM is loaded. You could wrap it into a `window.onload` function e.g. `window.onload = function () { filterSelection("all"); }`

Comment: I'm not sure how to fix it, but the problem seems to be with `document.getElementById("myBtnContainer")`, not the className, because it is saying that the myBtnContainer is null

Comment: Your code from line 38 to 47 should be inside the `window.onload` before the `filterSelection("all");`

Comment: @Nick that fixed the issue with the elements not displaying initially. The issue of the active state not being removed/added accordingly remains, but that is minor. Thanks!

Comment: @ParkerRichard you'll need to put *all* that code inside the `window.onload` function as well. Sorry didn't notice it earlier (I didn't scroll far enough)

Comment: @Nick I moved my ```<script src="js/custom.js"></script>``` from the ```<head>``` to the end of the ```<body>``` and that seemed to do the trick. Thanks for helping me figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lets try this:

```
var container = document.querySelector("#myBtnContainer");
let btns = Array.from(container.querySelectorAll(".btn"));
//let btn = buttons.filter(item => item.className === "btn active");
```

Now you have your list. So just add the event. I add this filter you might figure out how to work with the values.